# AWS CloudFront with custom HTTPS origin, only allow origin requests from CF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

When using CloudFront with a custom HTTPS origin, I have my DNS setup like this

```
domain.com -> A (Alias) -> CloudFront Distribution Alias
origin.domain.com -> IPaddress of HTTPS server
```

I realize that the origin server needs to be reachable from any of the edge locations, however it would be great if I could somehow configure my HTTPS origin server to only accept incoming connections from the CloudFront edges eliminating any possibility it could be accessed directly by a user/bot. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this for S3 or a web service?

Comment: This is for an HTTPS server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict with Cloud Front IP Addresses,

**CloudFront IP Address List:**

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

```
    {
      "ip_prefix": "13.32.0.0/15",
      "region": "GLOBAL",
      "service": "CLOUDFRONT"
    }
```

Search for  `CLOUDFRONT` as service in file and place IP Restrictions to your endpoints or to your security group. That will protect from anyone accessing other than cloudfront.

**Example of the implementation:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-update-your-security-groups-for-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-waf-by-using-aws-lambda/

**IP Address Range Change Event:**

What happens if the IP address list gets changed?

You can subscribe to Lambda and update your list automatically via lambda.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/subscribe-to-aws-public-ip-address-changes-via-amazon-sns/

**Additional Security:**

Enable secret headers from your CloudFront and make sure you are receiving the request only through your Distribution and not through others. This comes with the additional maintenance of keeping the header in a rotation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, I found this Lambda function which I will test: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-update-your-security-groups-for-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-waf-by-using-aws-lambda/

Comment: This is a potentially weak solution, by itself. Anyone can create a CloudFront distribution pointing to your origin server.  You should also use a secret CloudFront custom origin header and reject any request that lacks it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html#forward-custom-headers-restrict-access

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you. Added to the answer. We have been using it for the past two years and no issues of anyone else accessing our contents. Ideally, if they do, they will be making money for us, which we see as a positive one.